# How to monitor what resources are being loaded using OKHttp?

Tags: android, webview, okhttp, interceptor

`shouldInterceptRequest` is a very useful method which can be used with a `webview` to monitor the resources which are being requested by a webpage. I'm trying to achieve the same monitoring feature with `OKHttp` library as below.

for a webview:

```
WebView webview = new WebView(sourceContext);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            String url = String.valueOf(request.getUrl());
            Log.i("RESOURCES", url); // here I can monitor all urls requested to be loaded
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to achieve the same thing using `OKHttp` library, but its interceptor only gives me the main url, requested by me to be loaded:

```
    Request request = new Request.Builder().cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK).addHeader("Cookie", CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(INSTAGRAM_URL))
            .url(url)
            .build();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @NotNull
        @Override
        public Response intercept(@NotNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            Log.i("RESOURCES", request.url().toString()); // it only logs once, the main url requested by me for loading

            return response;
        }
    }).build();

    client.newCall(request).execute();
```

using `OKHttp`, how can I monitor all urls requested by the webpage for loading?